# Two buttons next to each other in a mobile navbar

Tags: buttons, mobile

I have a UX issue which would be simpler to solve if I had to buttons next to each other in the navbar for a mobile device.

In the images below I'm referring to the buttons marked 1 and 2.  2 Will in practice be a dropdown to handle additional options.

An additional question is that if it is workable, should the buttons be completely separate (lower chance of hitting the wrong button) or linked (visually simpler)?

[image: Two action buttons in mobile navbar sketch]

Good / bad idea?  Does anyone have any experience with this either working or failing?

The alternative seems to be having a single dropdown, but button 1 will be used fairly often, so putting it behind a menu seems like a bad idea.  Or is it?

[image]

Note: This question is related to some suggestions I received in [another](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10362/file-manager-on-a-mobile-device) topic

Comment: Is this for touch or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the additional options can be separated to 2 groups use two buttons with some space between them.

If they belong logically together use only on dropdown! 
(I would prefer this solution depending on the functions)

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite follow what you mean by "If they belong logically together use only on dropdown!".  Could you kindly elaborate on that for me?

Comment: Not sure, was 'on' meant to be 'one' maybe?

Comment: Yes on = one. I mean if the functions belong together for example CRUD functions than simply use one button which contains all of them.

Use 2 buttons if the functions can be easily, and logically separated into two different groups. For example 1. button: CRUD functions, 2. button: Share on Social networks

Answer (score 0):

If the two buttons are related, but don't make sense together try labeling button 1 with whatever it does/is called and make button 2 connected, like in the second image above, but simply as a downward-pointing triangle.

[image: Concept of what I was explaining]